# Uncaught ReferenceError: ContainerPanel is not defined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I created one panel in extjs.

When I execute this it's showing this error:
'Uncaught ReferenceError: ContainerPanel is not defined'

Please correct me where am I wrong.

My code can be seen below:

```
 Ext.application({
 launch : function(){
                Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
                    renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
                    width:400,
                    height:400,
                    title:ContainerPanel,
                    items: [
                            {
                                xtype:panel,
                                height:100,
                                width:200,
                                columnWidth:0.5

                            },

                            {
                                xtype:panel,
                                height:100,
                                width:200,
                                columnWidth:0.5

                            }]

                });
            }
```

});

Thanks

Comment: `title` is supposed to be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xtype` should be a string:

```
xtype: 'panel'
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but i put it panel as a string but still i am getting same error.

Comment: Thank you!!! now its working,,, Here title:'ContainerPanel' also should be string.